Ogr2ogr: How do I merge 2 geojson files?
I'm attempting to combine 2 geojson files using ogr2ogr, but I'm getting the following errors:
Running this from a windows cmd window:
ogr2ogr PROW.geojson Rural.geojson Urban.geojson

Returns this:

Unable to open datasource `Urban.geojson' with the
following drivers.

Running this from an AutoHotKey routine
runwait %comspec% /k ogr2ogr PROW.geojson Rural.geojson Urban.geojson

returns this:

Couldn't fetch requested layer 'Urban.geojson'!

I followed the instructions in item 4 here:
https://mapscaping.com/ogr2ogr-basics-cheat-sheet/
I tried multiple files in different orders, but it always returned the same error for the last geojson file.

I think you want to break this into two steps:

make a file in the format you want for your merged output
append the second file to the first

Something like (using some shapefiles I have lying around as an example):
ogr2ogr -f "geojson" output.geojson sa1_2016_aust_fixed_nsw.shp -nln sa1_2016_aust

(for your first layer). That command is saying run ogr2ogr, make a geojson file, call it output.geojson, from the data in the file sa1_2016_aust_fixed_nsw.shp, and name the layer sa1_2016_aust
and then
ogr2ogr -f "geojson" -update -append output.geojson sa1_2016_aust_fixed_vic.shp -nln sa1_2016_aust

This command is saying much the same - update and append tell it to add to your layer, and specifying the name again lets it know you want to add to the layer you created in the first step.
In my case, that produces one file called output.geojson which now contains one layer with the contents of the two separate spaital files.
Hope that helps
